# Find $\inf_{P_{X_1,X_2}}P_{X_1,X_2}(\|X_1-X_2\| > 2\alpha)$ , where $\alpha > 0$ and inf is over couplings

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\mathcal X$ be a *seperable* Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$, and let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random vectors on $\mathcal X$ with finite means.

> **Question.** Given $\alpha > 0$, what is value of, or an alternative expression for
>   $$
> h(\alpha):=\inf_{P_{X_1,X_2}}P_{X_1,X_2}(\|X_1-X_2\| > 2\alpha),
> $$
>   where the infimum is taken over all joint distributions $P_{X_1,X_2}$ of $X_1$ and $X_2$ ?

**Motivation.** It's well-known that $\text{TV}(X_1,X_2) = \inf_{P_{X_1,X_2}}P_{X_1,X_2}(X_1 \ne X_2)$. Thus, $h(0)=\text{TV}(X_1,X_2)$ in particular.

> **Conjecture.** $h(\alpha) =\inf_{\|z\| \le \alpha}\text{TV}(X_1-z,X_2+z)$.

---

## Edit: Proof of weaker form of conjecture: an upper bound

In the comments to this question and answers, many users have pointed out counter-examples to my Conjecture. Here, I'll settle to proof a weaker version: an inequality. For simplicity of notation, let $P_k$ be the distribution of $X_k$. Viz,

> **Theorem.** $h(\alpha) \le \inf_{\|z\| \le \alpha}TV(P_1-z,P_2+z)$.

User Iosif has established that

> $h(\alpha) = \sup\{P_1(U)-P_2(U^{2\alpha})\mid U \subseteq \mathcal X\text{ open}\},$

where $U^{\delta} = \{x_1 \in \mathcal X \mid d(x_1,U) \le \delta\}$ is the $\delta$-neighborhood of $U$, and $d(x_1,U) := \inf_{x_2 \in U}\|x_1-x_2\|$ is the distance of $x_1$ from the set $U$. I'll use this to proof the above theorem (the TV upper bound).

Now, for every $z \in \mathcal X$, we may translate all the open sets $U$ in the above formula without changing it. Indeed the invariance $\{U-z \mid U \subseteq \mathcal X\text{ open}\} = \{U \mid U \subseteq X\text{ open}\}$ is trivial to show. Thus,
$$
h(\alpha) = \sup\{P_1(U-z)-P_2((U-z)^{2\alpha})\mid U \subseteq \mathcal X\text{ open}\}.
$$
On the other hand, it is clear that $U+z \subseteq (U-z)^{2\alpha}$ whenever $\|z\| \le \alpha$. Indeed,
$$
x=u + z \in U + z \implies d(x,U-z) = d(u, U-2z) \le d(u,u-2z) = 2\|z\| \le 2\alpha.
$$
Thus $P_1(U-z)-P_2((U-z)^{2\alpha}) \le P_1(U-z)-P_2(U+z)$ $\forall$ open $U \subseteq \mathcal X$ and $\|z\| \le \alpha$.

$$
\therefore h(\alpha) \le \inf_{\|z\| \le \alpha}\sup\{P_1(U-z)-P_2(U+z)\mid U \subseteq \mathcal X\text{ open}\} = \inf_{\|z\| \le \alpha}TV(P_1-z,P_2+z).
$$
This completes the proof of the theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal X$ be a separable Banach space. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$, respectively. Then, by Theorem 11 (pp. 436-437) of [Strassen](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177700153) (used with $\omega=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathcal X\times\mathcal X\colon\|x_1-x_2\|\le2\alpha\}$), 
$$h(\alpha)=\sup\{\nu(U)-\mu(U^{2\alpha})\colon U\subseteq\mathcal X, U\text{ is open}\}, 
$$
where $U^\delta$ is the $\delta$-neighborhood of $U$.

In particular, it follows that indeed $h(0)=TV(\mu,\nu)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (upvoted). This Strassen is formula only *synthetic* and appears dreadful to "compute" with :). I was hoping for something more *analytic*. Concerning my small conjecture (which would be a bit more analytic), any thoughts ? Or maybe a modifed identity of tha ilk holds ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this expression for $h(\alpha)$ is about as "dreadful" as the definition $TV(\mu,\nu):=\sup\{\nu(U)-\mu(U)\colon U\subseteq\mathcal X, U\text{ is Borel}\}$ of the TV distance. As for you conjecture, I don't think it can be true; you can try checking the case of two real-valued normal (or uniform)  random variables.

Comment: The difference is that TV has other equivalent forms (e.g $TV = L_1/2$, etc.) which might more useful (at times) for doing certain "computations". I was wondering whether your expression for $h(\alpha)$ has any interesting alternative expressions ?

Concerning the conjecture, maybe it's an inequality rather equality. I'll check.

Comment: Using your formula, I've proven a weaker version of my conjecture; see edit to my question.

Comment: @dohmatob : I am glad you found this answer to be of use.

Comment: BTW, FWIW I also came up with an alternative proof of the inequality not using the formula ;) https://mathoverflow.net/a/337339/78539

Comment: I think the special case $\alpha=0$, in which we have a simpler expression for $h(\alpha)$, is intrinsically much easier than the general case. Indeed, for $\alpha=0$ the cost function $c(s,t):=1_{\|s-t\|>2\alpha}$ satisfies the triangle inequality $c(s,t)\le c(s,u)+c(u,t)$, which results in a great simplification of the mass transportation problem; cf. e.g. Theorem 9 and condition (6.5) in Kemperman's paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-46477-5_5. However, the triangle inequality fails to hold for $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Indeed, the case $\alpha = 0$ induces the "discrete metric" on $\mathcal X$, and so the scenario corresponds to total variation (= indeed simple). Yes, I also noticed that the general case is much more difficult and I'm now settling for just upper bounds. Also, in the general case, things still seem to simplify a great deal (e.g multi-variate gaussians with same covariance matrix). Maybe this can be extended to unimodal distributions, I don't know...

Also, thanks for the ref (unfortunated, can't access).

Answer (score 1):

As Iosif wrote, the conjecture does not hold. Suppose $\alpha=1$ and $X_1$ takes the values 0,1,2 with equal probability and $X_2$ takes the values 0,2 with equal probability. Then $h(1)=0$ but translates of these variables have TV distance at least $ 1/3$.

Comment: Yes, sure. Shouldn't this post be a comment ? Taking $2\alpha=1$, $P_1 = \delta_0$, and $P_2 = (1/2)\delta_{-1} + (1/2)\delta_1$ also gives another counter example...

Comment: Thanks for the input. This should have really been a comment. I've upvoted it anyways. Also, I've proven a weaker version of my conjecture, see below.

Comment: @dohmatob: "The result you conjectured is false" seems like a perfectly sound answer to me.

Comment: Well, such an answer is not a very significant as this (falsity) had been noticed in the comments to Iosif's answer already. Writing this up would fit the bill for a comment, but no an "answer" I guess...

Comment: I think this is a useful answer: Whereas I just said "I don't think it can be true" about the conjecture, Yuval disproved it.